# Swift 4 CATransition flipping UIView without 3D effect

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, 3d, catransition

I wanna flip an UIView in a ViewController without the 3D effect, is it possible to do that?

```
let transition = CATransition()
transition.duration = 0.5
transition.type = "flip"
transition.subtype = kCATransitionFromLeft

view.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution to propose if it suits your needs.
Instead of going with the rotation parameter you could play with the scale.
You will have a faked rotation with no perspective whatsoever.

Scale x for horizontal flip and Scale y for vertical.

You can do this as follow in view did load (or the button action function if you use a button to trigger the animation) :

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5) {
        self.yourViewName.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: -1, y: 1)
    }
```

I hope it can help you.

Comment: It definitely helps me :)